# SoftLayer : BareMetal Server : Configuration Details REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we are using below mentioned REST API, for getting configuration details for BM Servers.
REST API URL : 
https://{account_id}:{api_key}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/getCreateObjectOptions.

In the response, we will get keyName value and description.
Is there any standard format which is defined for keyName.
For example : S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID
At the beginning (S1270), we will get processor details.
After first underscore (_8GB),we will get RAM details in GB.
After second underscore,(_2X1TBSATA), we will get disk details.

Please share us more details related to the keyName format understanding.

Also let me know this format is constant or it will be changed in future (For example : RAM details at the beginning and processor details at the end 8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID_S1270)

fixedConfigurationPresets:
preset: 
description: Single Xeon 1270, 8GB Ram, 2x1TB SATA disks, Non-RAID,
keyName: S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID,
totalMinimumHourlyFee: .368,
totalMinimumRecurringFee: 244
template: 
fixedConfigurationPreset: 
keyName: S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID
preset: 
description: Single Xeon 1270, 32GB Ram, 1x1TB SATA disks, Non-RAID,
keyName: S1270_32GB_1X1TBSATA_NORAID,
totalMinimumHourlyFee: .595,
totalMinimumRecurringFee: 395
template: 
fixedConfigurationPreset: 
keyName: S1270_32GB_1X1TBSATA_NORAID
preset: 
description: Dual Xeon 2620, 32GB Ram, 4x1TB SATA disks, Non-RAID,
keyName: D2620_32GB_4X1TBSATA_NORAID,
totalMinimumHourlyFee: .786,
totalMinimumRecurringFee: 522
template: 
fixedConfigurationPreset: 
keyName: D2620_32GB_4X1TBSATA_NORAID

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation available about the format used in the items, I suggest you to submit a ticket and ask SoftLayer Guys for further assistance.